# Does Azure support container service for Recognize text API

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, azure-container-service

We are trying to use Azure recognize text api(https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5adf991815e1060e6355ad44/operations/587f2c6a154055056008f200)
 for detecting handwriting texts. I want to know whether a Container service is available for this API. I noted that container services are available for Read API and Analyze API.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should be using Read API. It is more robust than Recognize Text, and we will be announcing a deprecation of RecognizeText soon enough. Read API is the best in breed OCR engine in market.

Comment: Thanks for commenting. We can avoid detecting handwriting when we use RecognizeText api. Can we do the same using Read Api ? I didn't find such capability in ReadAPI . Please advise.